# RTMP stream of a+v plays only audio, no video

Tags: actionscript-3, netstream, netconnection

In Flash, AS3, I am using NetConnection to connect to a RTMP server, then I use NetStream to play a video+audio stream.

I attach the stream (attachNetStream) to a flash.media.Video instance that is added to stage (double checked that it is ON the stage) and play it, but all I get is the sound of the stream that's being played - no video is displayed.

Note that even though I cannot see the video, when I listen to the onMetaData of the stream I can get plenty of information about the video such as width, height, FPS (changes during playback as if a video is shown), number of decoded frames.

Does anybody have an idea how can I make the video work too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys! but I found out the answer:

Apparently Flash's (CS3) built-in `Video` class does not support `H.264` streams. I tried to compile the exact same code in Flex 3.5 and everything worked!

There is a possibility that CS4 also supports `H.264` streams. I did not try.

JWPlayer is great, I did not try Pyro.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "raw" NetConnection and NetStream and attach it to a flash.media.Video, I'd recommend using some wrapper such as [Pyro Player](http://code.google.com/p/pyro-player/). Its basically a video API and I've used it many times for RTMP video and it works like a charm (I've always found the Video component from Adobe very buggy, specially when displaying video from a RTMP server). Give it a try!